# Confused about the behavior of returned object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, find-by-sql

After firing a Model.find_by_sql as;

```
data = Setup::Type.find_by_sql ["SELECT value FROM table WHERE type_cd = 'print_format' AND subtype_cd = 'schedule_print_format'"]
```

The object is returned as;

```
#<Setup::Type:0x60c42f0>
#<Setup::Type:0x60c4140>
#<Setup::Type:0x60c3f90>
```

On using the 'inspect' function on data,it retruns

```
[#<Setup::Type value: "SalesReceipt_Bhindi_sch.rpt">, #<Setup::Type value: "SpecialOrder_Bhindi_sch.rpt">, #<Setup::Type value: "ReturnReceipt_Bhindi_sch.rpt">, #<Setup::Type value: "Takepayment_Bhindi_sch.rpt">]
```

On using data.class it returns Array.

However, this works just fine on using as a 'hash' as far as i presume,

```
data.each do |name|
  xml  =  Hpricot::XML(%{
                   <params>
                    <from_trans_date>#{date_for_transaction}</from_trans_date>
                    <to_trans_date>#{date_for_transaction}</to_trans_date>
                    <print_format>#{name.value}</print_format>
                    <company_id>#{company_id}</company_id>
                   </params>
    })
```

My question here is, why does 'data' behaves like an Hash, as per the implementation like 'name.value'.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find_by_sql` is returning an array of `Setup::Type` objects. When you are iterating over the array, you are getting an instance of `Setup::Type` which you are accessing using `name` variable. Hence `name.value` is working.

If you change `name` to `type_obj`, it would be more clear,

```
data.each do |type_obj|
  xml  =  Hpricot::XML(%{
                   <params>
                    <from_trans_date>#{date_for_transaction}</from_trans_date>
                    <to_trans_date>#{date_for_transaction}</to_trans_date>
                    <print_format>#{type_obj.value}</print_format>
                    <company_id>#{company_id}</company_id>
                   </params>
    })
```

This is from the documentation of [find_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class). Might help.

> Executes a custom SQL query against your database and returns all the
>   results. The results will be returned as an array with columns
>   requested encapsulated as attributes of the model you call this method
>   from. If you call Product.find_by_sql then the results will be
>   returned in a Product object with the attributes you specified in the
>   SQL query.